# Chrome Custom Tab support in capacitor

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor, chrome-custom-tabs

Is there any way to make Browser Tab work with a capacitor react project.
I found that it's supported in ionic. I'm relatively new to ionic and capacitor.
I'm trying to use this ionic plugin in my react capacitor
https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/cli

but I'm getting this error

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '/Users/userid/Desktop/projectname-irc/node_modules/@ionic-native/browser-tab'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found custom tabs are not part of capacitor docs, but they were working through [BrowserOptions](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/v2/apis/browser#browseropenoptions) passes in Browser.open method.

```js
    function openInBrowserTab() {
        Browser.open({ url: 'https://www.google.com/', presentationStyle: 'popover', windowName: '_self' });
    }
```

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/v2/apis/browser#open